# MODx 500 Server Error When Trying to Edit a Resource in Manager

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

I'm running MODx Revolution 2.0.8-pl (traditional) and get a blank page (500 Server Error) when trying to edit most resources in the Manager. The frontend and other Manager functions are all working fine.

I first noticed the issue after adding ~600 new resources to the site. (Unfortunately, I get the error on both new and old resources)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I increased the PHP memory limit to 64MB and the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

You should really just post this on the MODX forum... I bet there's more people with knowledge there, lol.

Server 500 errors are often caused by wrong permissions, for example files that are set to 777 while your server set up only allows 755.

Answer (score 1):

Just faced this same issue and it ended up being that I uninstalled TinyMCE but the plugin file was still enabled.

Answer (score 1):

I had to re-install TinyMCE in the most recent version after my MODX upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my MODX website works but `/manager` throws a 500 error.

It happened after I've removed `/www/core/cache/*`

First of all, I check logs:
`sudo tail -100 /var/log/apache2/error.log`

I see this error:
`Smarty: unable to create directory /var/www/html/core/cache/mgr/smarty/default`

So to fix this I added permissions:
`sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/*`